# Solve and NSolve hitting iteration limit for simple system

Tags: equation-solving

I'm am trying to get Mathematica to determine the intersection of a line and a parabola, like so:

```
Solve[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}]
```

But evaluating this gives `Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.` and `Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.`

Does this problem need to be expressed in some other way?

Comment: Try it again in a fresh Mathematica session

Comment: You surely have defined `x`or `y` previously

Comment: Thanks @belisarius, that was indeed the problem.   :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @belisarius noted, the problem here is that `x` and `y` were defined at an earlier point in the Mathematica session.

This kind of error can be prevented like so:

```
Block[{x, y}, Solve[{x + y == 6, x^2 == y}, {x, y}]]
```

which localizes `x` and `y`, correctly giving:

```
{{x -> -3, y -> 9}, {x -> 2, y -> 4}}
```

This problem is discussed in more detail in the [Lingering Definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562/14505) section of [Pitfalls for New Users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).

Comment: Speaking as a new user I also recommend to make use of `?` or `??` rather often to see if variables and or functions are internally implemented as desired. If not, as you mentioned `Block`would be a workaround or to use `Clear`

Comment: If we are going to take walkarounds ..`Solve[{\[FormalX] + \[FormalY] == 
   6, \[FormalX]^2 == \[FormalY]}, {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}]`